# Why can't I use IO constructor

Tags: haskell

Why can't I do this:

```
import Data.Char

getBool = do
  c <- getChar
  if c == 't' 
    then IO True 
    else IO False
```

instead of using `return`?

Comment: because there is no such function `IO` and `IO` is not a record

Comment: ``IO`` is a type constructor, not a value constructor. ``IO True`` would be a type, not a value (if ``True`` was a type).

Comment: @Bogdan, can you explain please, how is IO defined? Like this IO a = ...? And what's on the right hand side of `=`?

Comment: @Alex - it appears to be a pseudonym. :)

Comment: @Alex, see [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Type_constructor). ``IO`` itself is not even defined anywhere, because it is a magical built in type, but that's beside the point in this question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Background

I'll answer the slightly broader (and more interesting) question. This is because there is, at  least from a semantical standpoint, more than one IO constructor. There is more than one "kind" of `IO` value. We can think that there is probably one kind of `IO` value for printing to the screen, one kind of `IO` value for reading from a file, and so on.

We can imagine, for the sake of reasoning, IO being defined as something like

```
data IO a = ReadFile a
          | WriteFile a
          | Network a
          | StdOut a
          | StdIn a
          ...
          | GenericIO a
```

with one kind of value for every kind of `IO` action there is. (However, keep in mind that this is not actually how `IO` is implemented. `IO` is magic best not toyed with unless you are a compiler hacker.)

Now, the interesting question – why have they made it so that we can't construct these manually? Why have they not exported these constructors, so that we can use them? This leads into a much broader question.

### Why would you want to not export constructors for a data type?

And there are basically two reasons for this – the first one is probably the most obvious one.

#### 1. Constructors are also deconstructors

If you have access to a constructor, you also have access to a *de*-constructor that you can do pattern matching on. Think about the `Maybe a` type. If I give you a `Maybe` value, you can extract whatever is "inside" that `Maybe` with pattern matching! It's easy.

```
getJust :: Maybe a -> a
getJust m = case m of
              Just x -> x
              Nothing -> error "blowing up!"
```

Imagine if you could do this with `IO`. That would mean `IO` would stop being safe. You could just do the same thing inside a pure function.

```
getIO :: IO a -> a
getIO io = case io of
             ReadFile s -> s
             _ -> error "not from a file, blowing up!"
```

This is terrible. If you have access to the `IO` constructors, you can create a function that turns an `IO` value into a pure value. That sucks.

So that's one good reason to not export the constructors of a data type. If you want to keep some of the data "secret", you have to keep your constructors secret, or otherwise someone can just extract any data they want to with pattern matching.

#### 2. You don't want to allow any value

This reason will be familiar to object-oriented programmers. When you first learn object-oriented programming, you learn that objects have a special method that is invoked when you create a new object. In this method, you can also initialise the values of the fields inside the object, and the best thing is – you can perform sanity checking on these values. You can make sure the values "make sense" and throw an exception if they don't.

Well, you can do sort of the same thing in Haskell. Say you are a company with a few printers, and you want to keep track of how old they are and on which floor in the building they are located. So you write a Haskell program. Your printers can be stored like this:

```
data Printer = Printer { name :: String
                       , age :: Int
                       , floor :: Int
                       }
```

Now, your building only has 4 floors, and you don't want to accidentally say you have a printer on floor 14. This can be done by not exporting the `Printer` constructor, and instead having a function `mkPrinter` which creates a printer for you if all the parameters make sense.

```
mkPrinter :: String -> Int -> Maybe Printer
mkPrinter name floor =
  if floor >= 1 && floor <= 4
     then Just (Printer name 0 floor)
     else Nothing
```

If you export this `mkPrinter` function instead, you know that nobody can create a printer on a non-existing floor.

Comment: "you can create a function that turns an IO value into a pure value. That sucks." - but if you really really want to, [there is such a function in the standard library](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO-Unsafe.html) :)

Comment: Don't mention the `unsafePerformIO`! Treason! (I actually make a point of pretending it doesn't exist. When someone really needs it, they will know enough to find it on their own. This is based on my experience as a beginner being uncertain whether or not I want to use `unsafePerformIO`. I could have avoided a lot of confusion if I thought such a thing didn't exist.)

Comment: ReadFile s -> s "you can create a function that turns an IO value into a pure value. That sucks." -- and what value would "s" have?

Comment: @Alex The contents of the file, would make the most sense, if `IO` worked that way.

Comment: Could you please say more as to why `you can create a function that turns an IO value into into a pure value` sucks?

Comment: @KevinMeredith A lot of normal Haskell programming techniques break quickly when side effects are present. If we had a function `IO a -> a`, we could "hide" side effects inside functions that look pure, and then a lot of things would break.

Answer (score 15):

**You can use `IO` instead of `return`.** But not such easy. And you also need to import some inner modules.

Let's look at source of `Control.Monad`:

```
instance  Monad IO  where
    {-# INLINE return #-}
    {-# INLINE (>>)   #-}
    {-# INLINE (>>=)  #-}
    m >> k    = m >>= \ _ -> k
    return    = returnIO
    (>>=)     = bindIO
    fail s    = failIO s

returnIO :: a -> IO a
returnIO x = IO $ \ s -> (# s, x #)
```

But even to use  `IO` instead of `return`, you need to import `GHC.Types(IO(..))`:

```
newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
```

After this, you can write `IO $ \ s -> (# s, True #)` (`IO` is a State) instead of `return True`:

**Solution:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}  -- for unboxed tuples (# a, b #)
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}  -- then (,b) == \a -> (a, b)
import GHC.Types (IO (..))
import Data.Char

getBool = do
  c <- getChar
  if c == 't' 
    then IO (# , True #)
    else IO (# , False #)
```

Comment: Wow, even less magic. But `RealWorld` is still abstract, correct?

Comment: @nponeccop . This time, no. " `RealWorld` is deeply magical. ... it's only used in the type system, to parameterise `State#`" . "`State#` is the primitive, unlifted type of states. ... The only purpose of the type parameter is to keep different state threads separate.  It is represented by nothing at all."

Comment: It really sounds [deeply magical](http://this-plt-life.tumblr.com/post/44462204757/simon-peyton-jones-adding-the-io-monad-to-haskell).

Comment: When you use `import GHC.Types (IO (..))` what does the `(..)` mean?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai That line means "from the GHC.Types module, import the IO type, along with all its constructors." In this case, there is only one constructor, so it could have been written as `import GHC.Types (IO (IO))` – but the `..` notation to import all constructors is convenient for types where there are many constructors and you don't want to list them all.

Comment: This is quite insightful !!

Answer (score 5):

There is very little magic around `IO` and `ST` monads, much less than most people believes.

The dreaded IO type is just a `newtype` defined in [GHC.Prim](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-Types.html):

```
newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
```

First of all, as can be seen above the argument of `IO` constructor is not the same as the argument of `return`. You can get a better idea by looking at a naive implementation of `State` monad:

```
newtype State s a = State (s -> (s, a))
```

Secondly, IO is an abstract type: it's an intentional decision not to export the constructor so you can neither construct `IO` nor pattern match it. This allows Haskell to enforce referential transparency and other useful properties even in presence of input-output.