# Defining Applicative IO

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
 class (Functor f) => Applicative f where
   pure :: a -> f a 
   (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I tried to implement `Applicative IO`:

```
-- Learn You a Haskell is the author of all but the last line of code.
instance Applicative IO where
    pure = return
    a <*> b = do
        f <- a -- IO (a -> b)
        x <- b -- IO a. Now we need to apply (a -> b) on 'IO a' to get IO b'
        case f of IO g -> return g x    -- can't pattern match on IO...
```

This excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093720/409976) explains why the IO constructor cannot be used.

But how can I complete this instance?

Comment: (((Of course there's already an Applicative instance for IO lying around, you just need to `import Control.Applicative` to bring it into scope. This is a learning exercise.)))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right on track. Once you have extracted the values out of the `IO` monad using `<-` operator, you apply them to the function (`f x`) and wrap it back in the `IO` monad using `return` function.

```
m <*> n = do
        f <- m 
        x <- n 
        return $ f x
```

Ofcourse, these things work because `IO` is already an instance of `Monad` typeclass.

When you do `f <- m` you get `(a -> b)` in `f`. Similarly when you do `x <- n`, you get `a` in `x`. Now all you have to do is to apply the value of `x` in `f`. Once you have applied them you can wrap them up in `IO` constructor using `return` function. ( I have changed the variable names to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 6):

You're quite close but you've made two errors:

- You've misinterpreted the type of `f`. You've used the do-notation to obtain the result `f` of the computation `a`, so if `a` has type `IO (a -> b)`, then `f` must have type `a -> b`, while you seem to think that `f` is somehow still an `IO` computation.
- You write `return g x` while I think you mean `return (g x)`. The first applies `return` to two arguments: `g` and `x`, while the second applies `return` to a single argument: `g x`.

In short, you can complete the instance easily by dropping the case expression and just `return`ing `f x`.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at WrappedMonad from Control.Applicative, and especially its source code: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.1.0/docs/src/Control-Applicative.html#WrappedMonad

Basically <*> is ap and pure is return.